# Octave Logistic regression cost function error

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am doing Andrew Ng's ML course on Coursera. Week3 logistic regression cost function using Octave is giving me some errors. I think it's because of incorrect matrix multiplication. Can someone point out my mistakes please?

Data file for training data is located in File ex2Data1.txt which is available from here https://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/data/images/ex2.zip

```
data = load('ex2data1.txt');
X = data(:, [1, 2]); y = data(:, 3);
[m, n] = size(X);

% Add intercept term to x and X_test
X = [ones(m, 1) X];

% Initialize fitting parameters
initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);

% Compute and display initial cost and gradient
[cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y);
```

Code for my costFunction is as follows;

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
    
% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples


J = 0;
grad = zeros(size(theta));

    
%calculate hofX --> sigmoid theta'*X
hfX=sigmoid(theta'*X');

%cost --> bring '-' outside
J=-(1/m)*(y'*(log(hfX))')+(1-y)'*(log(1-hfX))';

%gradiant
fifth=(hfX-y)';
grad=(1/m)*(X'*fifth);
 
    
end
```

Code for the sigmoid function is as follows;

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
   
g = zeros(size(z));
      
g = (1./(1+e.^(-1*z)));
   
    
end
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: It's a while since I took this course (need to go back and complete it), but I do remember lots of people getting confused over the dimensions of their matrices, which order they should be in, and whether or not to use the transpose. The answer is to do a dimensional analysis and make sure you're getting the result you expect. The line `hfX=sigmoid(theta'*X');` is different to how I calculated it, and from there the cost calculation is different for me too.

Comment: ps I'm not giving an answer because I recall it's against the code of conduct for that course and it probably wouldn't help you much anyway because you really need to get your head around dimensional analysis to do well in the course. :)

Comment: Thanks all for your input I seem to have worked out the solution                     
%calculate hofX --> sigmoid theta'*X
hfX=sigmoid(X*theta);

%cost --> bring '-' outside
J=-(1/m)*(y'*(log(hfX)))+(1-y)'*(log(1-hfX));

%gradiant
fifth=(hfX-y)';
grad=(1/m)*(fifth*X);